# Custom buy/sell/transfer fee on a bridged ERC-20 token

Tags: ethereum, solidity, bitcoin, cryptocurrency, matic

Do tokens bridged on to another network maintain the tokenomics like selling fees and what not that was added to it on the original network? Is there a way to make it possible if not?

Answer (score 1):

> another network maintain the tokenomics like selling fees and what not that was added to it on the original network?

Any [token tax](https://tradingstrategy.ai/blog/transfer-fees-token-taxes-and-honeypots) is just a hacky gimmick. Listing the token in another DEX is enough to go around the tax. Also bridging the token gives a token another smart contract on the destination network, so none of the original rules will apply, because the original smart contract code is not run when token is being transferred in L2 or bridged blockchain.

This has been seen also [with NFTs when market places removed creator royalties](https://www.coindesk.com/web3/2023/02/15/blur-escalates-royalty-battle-with-opensea-recommends-blocking-platform/).

[One such token is Paxos Gold PAXG](https://tradingstrategy.ai/trading-view/polygon/tokens/0x553d3d295e0f695b9228246232edf400ed3560b5) where Polygon version is trading fee free, but the Ethereum mainnet version has a transfer fee.

> Is there a way to make it possible if not?

No. Token tax should not be part of the token long term, because Ethereum architecture is not constructed in a way to support this kind of functionality.

Comment: Anyway to prevent this from happening? I want the fee to be on whatever network it's on or just make the coin unbridgeable.

Comment: My answer one and polite way of saying no. There is no such thing as a real token tax.